# In angular 2, Pass obects with lot of proprities to forms (pop up) by double clicking datagrid

Tags: angular

There is  a data-table/grid.  When double  clicked  on one  data  row there, need  to  pass  relevant data item to a form. This selected item (object)  has  lots  of attributes.

What  is  the  best  way  to get this done without assigning values of attributes of the selected item one by one?

**Html code :**

```
<data-table 
    [items]="items" 
    [itemCount]="itemCount" 
    indexColumnVisible (reload)="reloadItems($event)" 
    (rowClick)="rowClick($event)"
    (rowDoubleClick)="openDetailsVatCodeModel(newVatCodeModal)"
    (rowDoubleClick)="rowDoubleClick($event)" 
    [rowTooltip]="rowTooltip">    

rowDoubleClick(rowEvent) {
    this.editVatdetails = rowEvent.row.item;
    //here  we  need pass  the  item to  form called "newVatCodeForm"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [routerLink] to pass the objects id into the element and onclick into a new component in which you fetch the data and fill out the form:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">
<md-icon>create</md-icon>
</button>
```